# Use Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017 without any Apple software installed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I would like to install Xamarin on my Visual Studio 2017 instance **without any apple software on my machine**.  Is this possible?

Currently Xamarin fails to install with an error that Bonjour service is not running.

> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Xamarin.Bonjour,version=1.0.13.1' failed to
> install
>
> Message Details: Service 'Bonjour Service' (Bonjour Service)
> failed to start.  Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start
> system services

Is there a workaround or does Xamarin installation require apple software to be installed?  I don't want Bonjour running on my machine let alone iTunes and I have no interest in running or developing an Apple compatible app.  I would like to develop for android for a run and personal use though.

Any ideas or workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio installer does not install any Apple software on your machine at all, and certainly not things like ITunes, etc.... I am not sure why you are getting the Bonjour error but if you look at the error message, this is actually a Xamarin.Bonjour component. Again, do not worry,  no Apple software will be installed. This is actually the opposite. Even though you can build an iOS app using Xamarin, Apple and Microsoft have a legal issue and Apple has stipulated that you can write the code in Visual Studio on Windows but any build or simulation must be on a Mac. This is not a technical limitation but rather a legal one.

What the Bonjour component is something called Mac agent that will allow Xamarin/Visual Studio to build against a remote Mac machine if you configure it to point to Mac and if you are trying to build iOS.

Comment: By the way, the error message sounds like you have some windows UAC settings or blocks and likely, other items can potentially fail to install or start as well. Make sure you are an admin and logged in as such. Check your UAC settings or right click the installer and choose to run as administrator

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I understand that Visual Studio won't install Apple components, but I'm sensing it is a prerequisite.  I am running the Visual Studio Installer as an Administrator.  A few more details include - there is no Bonjour service on my machine.  Some of the help I've found online included reinstalling iTunes before installing Xamarin.  Beyond that there are not any other fixes I have seen.

Comment: Wow, that just sounds like a bad or generic comment you read. I think ITunes could use Bonjour as well for the network data but I can assure you that the Xamarin one, that Xamarin installs is all that is installed and is only used for the Mac agent, network to a Mac from Windows for remote builds. I do not have any Apple software on my machine, no ITunes. VS 2017 installed just fine for me.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation that it is supposed to work.  It is helpful to know that.  Once i get it working (hopefully) i'll confirm here.

Comment: Well, this time everything worked.  Good information in your post even though I don't know why the installation didn't work the first 2 times.

Comment: Glad to hear. Good luck.